# Does every differentiable function have integrable derivative?

Tags: integration, derivatives

While it would seem to be true, I have found that there are examples of functions that are differentiable but not Riemann Integrable. Would a step function, for example, be integrable but not Riemann Integrable? So would all differentiable functions still be integrable in the general sense?

Answer (score 2):

No, consider the function $f:[-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by  $x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ with $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: That is the example that I have been seeing, are there any others?

Comment: @Roberto Hmm, can't seem to think of any, except the obvious replacing $\sin$ with $\cos$.

Comment: Most importantly, this example illustrates that the Lebesgue integral does not include the improper Riemann integral.  A more ambitious example would offer a derivative that is not integrable in either sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you take integrability in the sense of [Henstock-Kurzweil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral) then the answer to the question of the title of your post is yes! The amazing thing about the Henstock-Kuzweil integral is then that the fundamental theorem of calculus is valid for every differentiable function, without further assumptions: let
$$
f\colon [a,b]\rightarrow\mathbf R
$$
be a differentiable function. Then $f'$ is HK-integrable and
$$
\int_a^bf'=f(b)-f(a).
$$
The proof is very easy and a true marvel, showing that the HK-integral deserves much more attention than it gets.

Comment: The Henstock-Kurzweil integral dates from the 1950s.  Lebesgue knew that his integral did not integrate all derivatives and he had no solution to that.  By the next decade, 1910s, Denjoy and Perron had defined and studied extensively an integral that did handle all derivatives.  The Henstock-Kurzweil integral is just an equivalent reformulation of that integral.  If you know anything about Denjoy, he would be furious that his integral is attributed to an Irishman and a Czech.  He blasted the Perron integral (attributed to a German) because it (like the HK integral) is non constructive.